# Ubuntu 10.04 Postfix Dovecot ISPConfig 3 - send spam from own domain to random users

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

My Config:
Ubuntu 10.04 Postfix 2.7.0 Dovecot 1.2.9 ISPConfig 3.0.4.2

I've got the problem that a unknown / invalid user e.g dexter_rollins@xxxx> sends mails to different emails.

Every 5 - 7 min it's sending 10 emails with random senders and recipients but senders domain is managed by this server.

If I stop Apache it stops. Is there an solution how to find the error or miss configured form or is it possible to fix it with postfix?

mail.log shows this:

> Jan 24 22:00:30 xxxx postfix/qmgr[5489]: 342E47F580BA:
>   from=, size=1826, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Jan 24
>   22:00:30 xxxx postfix/qmgr[5489]: 3E9D77F58060:
>   from=, size=1708, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Jan 24
>   22:00:30 xxxx postfix/qmgr[5489]: B482A179F8854:
>   from=, size=1863, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Jan 24
>   22:00:30 xxxx postfix/qmgr[5489]: 198117F58090:
>   from=, size=1801, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Jan 24
>   22:00:30 xxxx postfix/qmgr[5489]: 580787F58091:
>   from=, size=1810, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jan 25 03:12:07 xxxx postfix/qmgr[20249]: 4BF9F179F85DE: from=<>,
>   size=4497, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Jan 25 03:12:07 xxxx
>   postfix/bounce[21727]: 60926179F85DF: sender non-delivery
>   notification: 4BF9F179F85DE Jan 25 03:12:07 xxxx postfix/qmgr[20249]:
>   60926179F85DF: removed Jan 25 03:12:07 xxxx postfix/pipe[21681]:
>   4BF9F179F85DE: to=, relay=dovecot, delay=0.02,
>   delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown) Jan 25
>   03:12:07 v postfix/qmgr[20249]: 4BF9F179F85DE: removed

apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

> Loaded Modules:
>   core_module (static)
>   log_config_module (static)
>   logio_module (static)
>   mpm_prefork_module (static)
>   http_module (static)
>   so_module (static)
>   actions_module (shared)
>   alias_module (shared)
>   auth_basic_module (shared)
>   auth_digest_module (shared)
>   authn_file_module (shared)
>   authz_default_module (shared)
>   authz_groupfile_module (shared)
>   authz_host_module (shared)
>   authz_user_module (shared)
>   autoindex_module (shared)
>   cgi_module (shared)
>   deflate_module (shared)
>   dir_module (shared)
>   env_module (shared)
>   expires_module (shared)
>   fcgid_module (shared)
>   include_module (shared)
>   mime_module (shared)
>   negotiation_module (shared)
>   php5_module (shared)
>   reqtimeout_module (shared)
>   rewrite_module (shared)
>   setenvif_module (shared)
>   ssl_module (shared)
>   status_module (shared)
>   suexec_module (shared)
>   suphp_module (shared)
>   unique_id_module (shared)
>   Syntax OK

httpd.conf is empty

apache2.conf: [apache2conf](http://pastebin.com/VzMvQBDY)

default vhost: [default vhost](http://pastebin.com/CgiPC8RV)

/etc/apache2/mods-available/

> actions.load
>   dav.load
>   php5.load
>   alias.load 
>   dav_lock.load 
>   proxy_ajp.load
>   asis.load 
>   dbd.load 
>   proxy_balancer.load
>   auth_basic.load
>   deflate.load 
>   proxy_connect.load
>   auth_digest.load
>   dir.load
>   proxy_ftp.load
>   authn_alias.load
>   disk_cache.load
>   proxy_http.load
>   authn_anon.load
>   dump_io.load
>   proxy.load
>   authn_dbd.load 
>   env.load
>   proxy_scgi.load
>   authn_dbm.load 
>   expires.load
>   reqtimeout.load
>   authn_default.load
>   ext_filter.load
>   rewrite.load
>   authn_file.load 
>   fcgid.load 
>   ruby.load
>   authnz_ldap.load
>   file_cache.load
>   setenvif.load
>   authz_dbm.load
>   filter.load
>   speling.load
>   authz_default.load
>   headers.load
>   ssl.load
>   authz_groupfile.load
>   ident.load
>   status.load
>   authz_host.load
>   imagemap.load
>   substitute.load
>   authz_owner.load
>   include.load
>   suexec.load
>   authz_user.load 
>   info.load
>   suphp.load
>   autoindex.load
>   ldap.load 
>   unique_id.load
>   cache.load
>   log_forensic.load 
>   userdir.load
>   cern_meta.load 
>   mem_cache.load
>   usertrack.load
>   cgid.load 
>   mime.load
>   version.load
>   cgi.load
>   mime_magic.load
>   vhost_alias.load
>   charset_lite.load
>   mod-security.load
>   dav_fs.load
>   negotiation.load

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled

> actions.load 
>   cgi.load
>   reqtimeout.load
>   alias.load 
>   deflate.load
>   rewrite.load
>   auth_basic.load
>   dir.load
>   setenvif.load
>   auth_digest.load
>   env.load ssl.load
>   authn_file.load
>   expires.load
>   status.load
>   authz_default.load
>   fcgid.load
>   suexec.load
>   authz_groupfile.load
>   include.load
>   suphp.load
>   authz_host.load
>   mime.load
>   unique_id.load
>   authz_user.load
>   negotiation.load
>   autoindex.load
>   php5.load

I've got this error message, too:

> Return-Path:  X-Original-To:
>   py.brancom@SPAMTRAP.INVALID Received: from www.mydomaim.de
>   (mail.mydomain.de [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])  by mx.selfip.biz (Spamtrap) with
>   ESMTP     for py.brancom@SPAMTRAP.INVALID; Sat, 04 Feb 2012 00:52:21
>   +0100 (CET) Date: Sat, 4 Feb 2012 00:52:20 +0100 To: py.brancom@SPAMTRAP.INVALID From: "Levitra Sales"
>    Subject: Hi, get 64% better prices,
>   quod hand carpalin Message-ID:
>   <006201c45adb$abad5f76$6165497e@levitra.sales@mail2mitch.com>
>   X-Priority: 3 **X-Mailer: ZuckMail [version 1.00]** MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset="UTF-8"

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior stops when apache is stopped, then it's likely that your apache configuration allows for some sort of proxy-ing, which is being abused by the spammer to send mail through your machine.

Start with this: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse

Also, check your httpd log files, and look for suspicious entries, specifically ones that do not reference the URLs that you actually host.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
the apache proxy modul is not loaded.


access.log

xx.xx.xx.xx - - [22/Jan/2012:03:09:42 +0100] "GET http://174.xx.xx.xx/judge.php HTTP/1.1" 404 526 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"


Telnet:

HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out


apache2/error.log look normal

Comment: edit: if found athis entry in the access.log
65.xx.xx.xx - - [22/Jan/2012:05:12:43 +0100] "POST http://65.xx.xx.xx:25/ HTTP/1.0" 200 297 "-" "-"

Comment: It's that second one, with the POST 65.xx.xx.xx:25 that would appear to be the trigger.  The 200 status code indicates that it worked, as far as apache is concerned, and so I still suspect that you have some sort of proxy installed.  Check the httpd.conf, any included configs, anything in conf.d, and any .htaccess files for any mention of proxy.  Also are you running mod_php or mod_perl?  Maybe a full dump of your configs would be in order.

Comment: for the moment thanks a lot. i posted the apache2 and the default vhost setting. do you need more logs?

Comment: I would also want to see /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
and /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf, and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Check for suspicious or altered files in your virtualhost.

Check for active suspicious process (`ps aux`).

Check httpd access.log entries with date/time immediately before the postfix accepting mail for delivery notification.

Comment: i checked the access.logs of the websites and found malicious code in a wordpress install

Comment: Are you using an outdated Wordpress? If yes, update it to the latest version. Are you using outdated plugins? If yes, update them to the latest version and if they are unmaintained for years switch to alternative plugins with similar functions but maintained. Since you cannot be sure to have completely cleaned your site, it's highly advisable to recreate from scratch the Wordpress install (re-downloading core and plugins), changing wp-config.php to point to the old database and then move you wp-content directory to the new install.